# Plot the solution over a particular region of the mesh

Tags: mesh, finite-element-method

I'm solving a linear elasticity problem using Finite Element package in Mathematica. I want to visualize the difference between unreformed and deformed meshes.

The displacement field is very localized at the particular region.  I need a very fine mesh to resolve the solution of the displacement in the follow figure. For example, The very localized deformation is highlighted in the red box (For simplicity, I refine the mesh along all the bottom region).
[image]

The contour plot of the vertical displacement file looks like this:
[image]

As we can see, the deformation is very high at the bottom tip.

But the magnitude of the displacement ($O(10^{-4})$) is very small compared to the domain size ($O(1)$). Therefore. When I overlap the underfunded and deformed meshes,

```
Show[{mesh2[
   "Wireframe"[{"MeshElement" -> "BoundaryElements", 
     "ElementMeshDirective" -> 
      Directive[EdgeForm[{Thin, Gray}], FaceForm[]]}]], 
  ElementMeshDeformation[mesh2, {u0, v0}][
   "Wireframe"[{"MeshElement" -> "BoundaryElements", 
     "ElementMeshDirective" -> 
      Directive[EdgeForm[{Thin, Red}], FaceForm[]]}]]}]
```

there is no observable difference between them.

[image]

Is there a way to overlap the underfunded and deformed meshes for a particular region (e.g., the region highlighted in red box), so that we can visualize the difference between them? And also plot the displacement over the deformed mesh in this particular region.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make use of `PlotRange->{{…},{…}}` as an argument to Show and so limit the plot to the relevant part.

Comment: Why I forget this command. Thanks @user21.